# AttributeError: 'InstagramAPI' object has no attribute 'direct_message'

Tags: python, instagram

I want to send direct by Instagram. 
this is my code

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
import re
username="********"
InstagramAPI = InstagramAPI(username, "***********")
InstagramAPI.login()
InstagramAPI.direct_message("hey", 5580539929)
```

but I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yasin/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/Include/yas.py", line 17, in <module>
    InstagramAPI.direct_message("hey", 5580539929)
AttributeError: 'InstagramAPI' object has no attribute 'direct_message'
```

what shuld I do?

Comment: don't use name `InstagramAPI` all over the place, e.g. as variable name

Answer (score 0):

you should use from direct_message but your args in function must to be direct_message(api,message,userid)
or use from python api source code for instagram that same this code:

```
    if type(recipients) != type([]):
        recipients = [str(recipients)]
    recipient_users = '"",""'.join(str(r) for r in recipients)
    endpoint = 'direct_v2/threads/broadcast/text/'
    boundary = self.uuid
    bodies   = [
        {
            'type' : 'form-data',
            'name' : 'recipient_users',
            'data' : '[["{}"]]'.format(recipient_users),
        },
        {
            'type' : 'form-data',
            'name' : 'client_context',
            'data' : self.uuid,
        },
        {
            'type' : 'form-data',
            'name' : 'thread',
            'data' : '["0"]',
        },
        {
            'type' : 'form-data',
            'name' : 'text',
            'data' : text or '',
        },
    ]
    data = self.buildBody(bodies,boundary)
    self.s.headers.update (
        {
            'User-Agent' : self.USER_AGENT,
            'Proxy-Connection' : 'keep-alive',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(boundary),
            'Accept-Language': 'en-en',
        }
    )
    #self.SendRequest(endpoint,post=data) #overwrites 'Content-type' header and boundary is missed
    response = self.s.post(self.API_URL + endpoint, data=data)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        self.LastResponse = response
        self.LastJson = json.loads(response.text)
        return True
    else:
        print ("Request return " + str(response.status_code) + " error!")
        # for debugging
        try:
            self.LastResponse = response
            self.LastJson = json.loads(response.text)
        except:
            pass
        return False
```